# Stack trace error, possible DB issue after module installation

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, frontend-error

I have installed an extension from connect and ran into an exception problem.  The website will not load and shows this error message:

> html/app/code/local/Ktree/Brand/sql/brand_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php"
>   - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'brand' already exists

I cannot log into magento connect to uninstall it either :(

Running CE 1.9.3.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems you have a database table called **brand** already exist in your data base. What you can do is

Disable the module by editing the **Ktree_Brand.xml** in the **app\etc\modules** by typing the `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>`

Some time your core_resource table is not updating with the version of the module,Check that also.

Comment: Hi Mujahidh, I disabled extension and have connect access, thanks for tip. Completely forgot about etc/modules!